# Customize Django ListView Pagination

Tags: django, elasticsearch

im implementing a Django ListView for a Search View. The search is done using Elasticsearch and django-elasticsearch-dsl. Im actually getting a pagination of just 10 items because thats the amount of contents that Elasticsearh answers by default. I could ask elasticsearch to get all the contents but it would be really unnefficient since im only showing like 50 of them.

Is there any way that Django reads the pagination information from other than the queryset?

This is what my view looks like:

```
from .elastic import search

class SearchView(ListView):
   template_name = "search/index.html"
   paginate_by = 50

   def get_queryset(self):
      keyword = self.kwargs['keyword']
      lang = get_language()
      return search(keyword, lang)
```

**Edit:**

When using a normal queryset from database, django manages the pagination, i assume that using a query for count the total amount of objects and by using the paginate_by parameter. In my case, the queryset that i return on the get_queryset method, is only one page lenght because i get those contents from elasticsearch. Im looking for a way to tell django how much contents the query has in total to let django build the pagination ok.

My search method is a query to elasticsearch that returns a page of contents in a queryset. But it doesnt return all the contents. I have the total amount of search results but i dont know where to put that variable to allow django build the pagination.

Comment: There are a number of ways to customize pagination. Could you be a bit more specific about what you need?

Comment: I need to specify django the total amount of contents because my queryset only has one page length and django assumes that there are no pages.

Comment: [This implementation might help you understand what’s needed](https://github.com/jaddison/django-simple-elasticsearch/blob/master/simple_elasticsearch/search.py)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but doing it for people who land on this.
The issue here is that Elasticsearch returns `paginate_by` results so Listview paginator will try to paginate those 50 results. As a result page 2 will always return 'No results'.

So the idea here is to get the paginator to always return 1 and handle the pagination on ElasticSearch instead:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

class SinglePagePaginator(Paginator):
    def validate_number(self, number):
        return 1
```

Then your listView

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    ...
    paginate_by = 10
    paginator_class = SinglePagePaginator
    
    def get_queryset(self):
            # Query Elasticsearch
            search = Search(index='index_name')
            multi_match = MultiMatch(query=query, fields=['field_name'])
            search = search.query(multi_match)

            # Adjust start and size of results
            search = search.extra(from_=start_from, size=page_size)
            response = search.execute()
```

So the default pagination will always return 1 but you handle it on Elasticsearch.

Another approach is to load all the results from ElasticSearch but it might get heavy on memory.